# Hover on image apear another images

Tags: wordpress, hover

When someone put his mouse on image A, then the B & C will appear (both) left, how could i do that?
(image will be animated)
Thank you!

https://scontent-a-mxp.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn2/t1.0-9/p600x600/1797512_456367017831227_7994715989917332805_n.jpg

(EDIT: Wordpress)

Comment: You didn't even specify what platform you want to do this on. Come on...

Comment: You need to use the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` attribute in your `<img>` tag and write some javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Could someone help me with that? If i  knew how to do that i wouldn't ask.. thank you anyway :)

Answer (score -1):

This short post explains how to create an image rollover animation for your Wordpress site in seconds using a plugin. No code necessary. Hope it helps you.

http://wpvisualslideboxbuilder.com/how-to-create-a-wordpress-slide-box/

Comment: Link-only answers are strongly discouraged here at Stack Overflow.  Instead, [it is preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Well, the link is to the plugin's website where it can downloaded. As  I shortly explained in the description above the link, the plugin does exactly what this question is asking. So any other explanation is redundant.